# Extract text and categories information of wikipedia articles from its html page

Tags: html-parsing, wikipedia

I have fetched a set of wikipedia articles in html format from web. I need to extract the plain text describing the article and categories information to which the article belongs?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question and what have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grab categories it is easier to use the API than parse HTML.

The API is documented here: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php